# Window.open() to open a url passed through a json file?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ionic-framework, window.open

I am building an ionic app for android and ios, using html code. I am trying to call a link from a json file stored on a server with a field name of link, but the window.open() will not recognize this, can someone please help?

```
<a onClick="window.open({{item.link}}, '_blank', 'location=yes')">
```

Tried to use href's but they only open the link in a browser which doesn't allow the user to back out of when tested, they have to exit the app completely to get back.

Any help would be appreciated. It seems to only be on ios which they happens.

GOT IT SORTED

```
<a href="{{item.link}}" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank',location=yes); return false;">
```

Comment: What do you mean *href's but they only open the link in a browser*? If you really want to use the onclick attribute (which does not seem the right way to me), then at least prefix it with `"javascript:window.open..."`. You might also need to wrap the double brace expression in single quotes.

Comment: put `{{item.link}}` inside quotations.

Comment: Whenever I wrap the double brace expression in single quotes, it tries to search for {{item.link}} rather than the data I am trying to collect. In other words it reads {{item.link}} as the data itself.

Comment: I am not familier with IONIC but I am pretty sure it uses `AngularJs`, right? If yes I'd be able to help. :)

Comment: any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: @CaolánMcKeown, I have posted a js-fiddle and answer, I hope this is what you were trying to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT SORTED

```
<a href="{{item.link}}" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank',location=yes); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `href` with `target`:

```
 <a href="{{item.link}}" target="_blank">
```

According to the [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref), you should in fact prevent that the link is available to the user before AngularJS is loaded, as follows:

```
 <a ng-href="{{item.link}}" target="_blank">
```

Or, if you really want to go with `onclick` then add "javascript:" and wrap the link in single quotes:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('{{item.link}}', '_blank', 'location=yes')">
```

#### Use a plug-in for forcing "target" links to open in external browser

When links open in the WebView there are no ways for the user to get back to the previous view.

[This article](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jul/02/External-Links-in-Cordova-for-iOS#TheInAppBrowserPlug-in) sheds some light on this:

> Luckily there's a `cordova.inAppBrowser` plug-in that encapsulates this hack in an easy to add plug-in. This is a much simpler solution that doesn't require hacking the generated cordova WebView wrapper code that can be overwritten by updates. The plug-in basically provides the ability for  `window.open()` to open a new window in the external browser.
>
> You can add this plug in with:
>
> ```
> cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
> ```
>
> in your Cordova project or – if you're using Visual Studio's Cordova Tools by adding it from the Visual Studio add-in Configuration page.
>
> The plugin basically replaces the `window.open()` function inside of the WebView control and so causes a new instance of the device browser to open – on iOS that'd be Safari.

Comment: These examples work fine on android when testing on the emulator, but on ios they open using the inapp browser with no way to exit. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you create the app? With Phonegap? Or Cordova? Or is this a webapp?

Comment: I am using Cordova to develop the app.

Comment: I think you need to check whether you have white-listed all URLs: read this: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/appdev/whitelist/. You should anyway not white list all URLs. Those that are not should normally stay within the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familier with IONIC, but I am pretty sure that Ionic uses angularjs so ....

Following works for me!

//Followiing HTML

```
<div>       
    <div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <ion-content style="display:block">
         <a href="" ng-click="openUrl(item.link)">Open in new</a>

        </ion-content>
    </div>     
</div>
```

And following Controller

```
var SampleApp;
(function (SampleApp) {

    var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ionic']);    
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.item = {
           link: 'http://example.com'
        }
        $scope.openUrl = function(url){
                  window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes')
        }
    });

})(SampleApp || (SampleApp = {}));
```

JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daveamit/r2c8dfhx/1/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

for me

```
<a href="{{item.url}}" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_self');">
   {{menu.title}}
</a>
```

work perfect.
'location=yes' was producing error as-

```
2     001637   error    Uncaught ReferenceError: yes is not defined, http://localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=android, Line: 1
```

now it is working good.